# In Swift, changing in function doesn't work in outside

Tags: json, swift, function, uitableview

I have a tableview. `cekilecek_data` contains tableview datas. I get some datas from JSON and I want to append this datas to tableview. But I have to do this inside of `jsonGetir()`. However, it does not work. `kodJSON` and `kodlarJSON` are nil in `viewDidLoad()`. Also, `cekilecek_data.append(kodJSON[1])` it doesn't add the datas to the table.

How do I fix it?

```
var cekilecek_data = ["Fenerbahçe", "Chelsea", "Arsenal"]
var kodlarJSON:String = ""
var kodJSON:[String] = []

func jsonGetir(){

    let urls = NSURL(string: "http://gigayt.com/mackolik/deneme.php")
    let sessions = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(urls!){

        data, response, error -> Void in

        if (error != nil){ print(error) }

        do {

            if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {

                kodlarJSON = jsonResult["kodlar"] as! String //101,102,103
                kodJSON    = kodlarJSON.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
                cekilecek_data.append(kodJSON[1]) //Here doesn't work!

            }

        }

        catch { print(error) }

    }

    sessions.resume()

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reload your tableview after you got data from server this way:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

And your final code will be:

```
func jsonGetir(){

    let urls = NSURL(string: "http://gigayt.com/mackolik/deneme.php")
    let sessions = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(urls!){

        data, response, error -> Void in

        if (error != nil){ print(error) }

        do {

            if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {

                self.kodlarJSON = jsonResult["kodlar"] as! String //101,102,103
                self.kodJSON    = self.kodlarJSON.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
                self.cekilecek_data.append(self.kodJSON[1]) //Here doesn't work!

            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.tableView.reloadData()  //Reload tableview here.
            }

        }

        catch { print(error) }

    }

    sessions.resume()

}
```

Comment: Happy to help you..:)

Answer (score 0):

With `kodJSON = kodlarJson.componentsseparatedByString(",")` you are creating an Array of only one object. Then with `cekilecke_data.append(kodJSON[1])` you are trying to append your data with the second object from this array that you have only set one object to.

```
do {

        if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {

            kodlarJSON = jsonResult["kodlar"] as! String
            kodJSON    = kodlarJSON.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
               // this line sets kodJSON:[String] to ["kodlar"]
            cekilecek_data.append(kodJSON[1]) //Here doesn't work!
               // this tries to append cekilecek_data from index [1] or second slot of kodJSON which only has one entry
        }

    }
```

if you change line to `kodlarJSON = jsonResult["kod,lar"] as! String`, it would work because kodJSON[1] would equal "lar"